# Modify Floating Action Button Default Green Border

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have a voice to text dictation application that acts as a microphone utility for a web hosted EMR platform.

We have multiple screens on this app, and one of the screens we have reserved to display only the spoken text.

In the interest of space for the text, I've decided to implement Floating Action Button and use that as a clickable microphone that will start our voice to text engine.

My question is, has anyone else had issues with a default greenish border being placed around a drawable used as the FAB src and how did you manage to modify it or get rid of it completely?

You will see my fab at the top center of the image, with the tiny little microphone being squished by that teal border.

My apologies, not enough reputation to post images, here's a link:
[Screenshot on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucT5Q.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/lyt_main">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_recording_0"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android.support.design:fabSize="normal"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/black"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="55dp"
    app:elevation="36dp"
/>

<com.applicadiamobile.dictation.adapter.CustomViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="false" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/drag_bar_gradient"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="9dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF" >

    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</com.applicadiamobile.dictation.adapter.CustomViewPager>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/undo"
            style="@style/btnStyleUndo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_small_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/undo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_doc"
            style="@style/btnStyleNewDoc"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_small_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            style="@style/btnStyleSend"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_small_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btn_send" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings_button"
            style="@style/btnStyleSettings"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_small_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/button_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/settings" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should not be brief and post your XML because your problem is most certainly there.

Comment: Okay I will add it...the button layout you see is hidden when our app is run on a tablet

Comment: Try removing all the customization from your button. leave only id, width, height and src and check what does it do. Also can you post your mic png image?

Comment: I have tried removing all other properties leaving only the four you mention with no results. I also tried removing any references to it in Java with no results. Like I was saying in my original post, changing the XML seems to have no effect on it. Could it be related to AppTheme or the default style it is set to?